# How to use compositeData in HTML tags

Tags: xpages

I have the following code in 8.5.3

```
<xp:div>
    <xp:this.attrs>
          <xp:attr name="data-theme" value="#{javascript:compositeData.data_theme}" />
          <xp:attr name="data-position" value="#{javascript:compositeData.data_position}" />
          <xp:attr name="data-role" value="footer" /> 
    </xp:this.attrs> 
</xp:div>
```

works fine. But the customer has Domino 8.5.2. And this version neither does support `tagName` and `attr`. And I have the values for the `attr` computed.

How can I use compositeDate in a construct like

```
<div data-position="#{javascript:compositeData.data-position}" ...
```

??

A workaround is to use computed Text

```
<xp:text escape="false" id="ctFooterDivStart">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<div data-theme='"+ compositeData.data_theme + "' data-position='" + compositeData.data_position + "' data-role='footer'>"}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

But this is butt-ugly and hard to read.

Comment: You don't need the javascript prefix, but the syntax you listed should be valid. Any attribute on a passthru element should support EL.

Comment: Thx, Tim.

tried this

<div data-theme="#{compositeData.data_theme}" data-role="footer">

It shows no error in designer but a error 500 in the browser

Comment: Your code `<div data-position="#{javascript:compositeData.data_position}"...` would work as is. It worked for me on 8.5.1 and 8.5.3. So it should work also work on 8.5.2.

Comment: Pretty ugly solution could be to render opening and closing tag for div in computed texts...

Answer (score 1):

The workaround so far is to write data_position instead of data-position in the source tab to make shure, designer creates the code without errors.

Next I have a small scriptblock on my page to replace all data_position with data-position

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('div[data_position ]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-position ', $(this).attr('data_position ')); //does the switch
    $(this).removeAttr('data_position '); //clears out the old one
});});
```

Just a workaround ( idea ).  Not checked, if this really is the best way in terms of performance. ...

Answer (score 1):

What about using a theme for this?

```
<control>
    <name>div-data-theme</name>
    <property mode="override">
        <name>value</name>
        <value>${javascript:@Char(60) + "div data-theme='" + compositeData.data_theme + "' data-position='" + compositeData.data_position + "' data-role='footer'" + @Char(62) + @Char(60) + "/div" + @Char(62)}</value>
    </property>
    <property mode="override">
        <name>escape</name>
        <value>${javascript:false}</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

*(The @Char's are required because you cannot use brackets in themes and CDATA is not working)*

In your custom control you can use this by adding a *xp:text* element:

```
<xp:text themeId="div-data-theme">
</xp:text>
```

If you don't add an id to the *xp:text* component it will not surrounded by a span tag.

Comment: ok, i have just rwritten the code to use scriptblocks, but themes look promising. will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I now decided to use computed text. There is not too much code involved. So the code is still readable. 
Here is an example for a collapsible-set ( accordion )

```
...
<xp:text escape="false">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:var html = "<div " 
            html = html + "data-role='collapsible-set' " 
            html = html + "data-mini='" + compositeData.data_mini + "' "
            Html = html + "data-theme='" + compositeData.data_theme + "' " 
            html = html + "data-inset='" + compositeData.data_inset + "' "
            html = html + "data-iconpos='" + compositeData.data_iconpos + "' " 
            html = html + "data-content-theme='" + compositeData.data_content_theme + "' " 
            html = html + "data-collapsed-icon='" + compositeData.data_collapsed_icon + "' " 
            html = html + "data-expanded-icon='" + compositeData.data_expanded_icon + "'> " 
            return html}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:callback facetName="fctAccordion" />
<xp:text escape="false">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"</div> "}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

...